# function that is continuous everywhere but not differentiable at x=1

Tags: calculus

So I easily came up with an example of a function that is continuous on $(-\infty, \infty)$, but not differentiable at $x=1$. I used $f(x)=|x-1|$. However, a friend in my calculus course asked me a question which I had trouble answering. He asked if $g(x)=\sqrt{x-1}$ also satisfies this. Now this function technically doesn't satisfy the definition of continuity used in a calculus course, because since any $x<1$ is not in the domain of this function, $g(x)$ DNE for such $x$. I told him that this function was not continuous on $(-\infty, \infty)$, but rather on its own domain. Was I correct in telling him this? Thank you.

Comment: take the derivative and plug in x=0 What happens?

Comment: Touché, imranfat. The derivative DNE for all $x<1$. Got it.

Comment: Saying that $x\mapsto \sqrt{x-1}$ isn't continuous on $(-\infty, +\infty)$ is meaningless because it's not even defined there.